# Android Graphical Layout Text Position Not Match Virtual Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

All text on Graphical Layout have float to the right side, but it shows at the centre in the Emulator. The position of the text in Graphical Layout and Virtual Emulator are not match. Any idea what caused this to happen? I am very new to android, thanks for helping me out.

I wanna place the text in the centre, even though the Emulator is placing the text in the centre, but it still annoying me the text floating to right in the Graphical Layout.

Images:

[Graphical Layout View](http://unlimitshop.metal-warehouse.com/1.png)

[Emulator View](http://unlimitshop.metal-warehouse.com/2.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >



       <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:src="@drawable/top" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/billTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:text="@string/bill_text_view" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/activityView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blk_activity"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/topView" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topView" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/problemsSpinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/activityView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/activityView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/activityView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/activityView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
    android:entries="@array/problem_solving"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_list" />

<!-- DURATION -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/durationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blk_duration"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/activityView" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activityView"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/durationTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/durationView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/durationView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/durationView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/duration"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_duration"

         />



<!-- DISTANCE -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/distanceView"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blk_distance"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/durationView" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_below="@+id/durationView"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/distanceTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/distanceView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/distanceView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/distanceView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="45dp"
        android:text="@string/distance"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_med" />


<!-- HEART -->


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/heartView"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/distanceView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/durationView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/distanceView" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/blk_heart" />


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/heartTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/heartView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/heartView"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/heartView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="45dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:text="@string/heart"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_med" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire code please?

Comment: Added Images of Graphical Layout View and Emulator View, Please help. Many Many Thanks

Comment: The layout looks fine to me and it's rendering well on my development platform. You shouldn't be facing any problem running it on a device. If you still do, let me know and I'll give you a different layout to work with.